# why laravel collective print &#039 in this code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I want to generate html attribute like data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"', but loravel collective print data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999-9999'" and use "& # 0 3 9". why?

```html
    {!! Form::text('mobile', null, ['class' => 'form-control text-left', 'data-inputmask' => '"mask": "(999) 999-9999"', 'data-mask']) !!}
```

```
laravel collective output:
```

```html
<input class="form-control text-left" data-inputmask="&#039;mask&#039;: &#039;(999) 999-9999&#039;" data-mask name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
```

but i want :

```html
<input class="form-control text-left" data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999-9999'" data-mask name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
```

Answer (score 1):

These are [escape characters.](https://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Try swapping your single quotes for double quotes for `data-inputmask`:

```
{!! Form::text('mobile', null, ['class' => 'form-control text-left', 'data-inputmask' => "'mask': '(999) 999-9999'", 'data-mask']) !!}
```

More information on [single quoted strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).